# How to retain text box values after postback in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 form in the single view and below are the code.

```
 @model MCRP.Models.tblRequest
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Review Request";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertForm", "Home"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactEmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new {id = "txtdelivery"} })
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validate();" value="submit" id="submitfilteration" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home"))
{
     Are you sure you want to delete Property ?
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
}
```

But on click of delete button, the text inserted in the txtdelivery get disappear

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ReviewRequest()
{         

        if (Session["AddtoCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["AddtoCart"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.addedtocart = (DataTable)Session["AddtoCart"];
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.addedtocart = null;
                ViewBag.EmptyCart = "Your Cart Is empty";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.addedtocart = null;
            ViewBag.EmptyCart = "Your Cart Is empty";
        }
        return View();

}
public ActionResult InsertForm(tblRequest Request)
{
       int requestid = 0;
        int RequestProperty = 0;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsUpsDelTbl_Request"))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "InsertRequest");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgencyName", Request.AgencyName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", Request.Contact);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", Request.DeliveryAddress);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPhone", Request.ContactPhone);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactEmailAddress", Request.ContactEmailAddress);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Request.Notes);
                    requestid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    con.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { throw ex; }
            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsUpsDelTbl_Request"))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = (DataTable)Session["AddtoCart"];
                try
                {
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        con.Open();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "InsertRequestProperty");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestID", requestid);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyID", dt.Rows[i]["PropertyId"].ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString());
                            RequestProperty= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        }
                        con.Close();
                        if (requestid > 0 && RequestProperty>0)
                        {
                            TempData["InsertRequestProperty"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RequestAdded"].ToString().Replace("{@requestid}", Convert.ToString(requestid));
                            Session["AddtoCart"] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { throw ex; }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ReviewRequest");
}
public ActionResult Delete(FormCollection property)
{            
 string PropertyID = "";
        foreach (var key in property.AllKeys)
        {
            PropertyID = property["hddeleteGroupid"];
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (Session["AddtoCart"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["AddtoCart"];
            for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
                if (dr[0].ToString() == PropertyID)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(dr);
                }
            }
            Session["AddtoCart"] = dt;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ReviewRequest");

}
```

**As I am new in MVC I don't know please help me out**

**More Detail** My page more detail is as shown in figure

[image]

Now on click of delete one popup with delete dialog gets open and on pressing of delete button one item added in the cart get deleted and also the text inserted in textbox get disappear,

[image]

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? You can only ever post one form at a time so why do you have 2 forms. And when you submit your redirecting to another page so unless you pass the value of the textbox to the `Delete()` POST method, and then to the `ReviewRequest` GET method, then the value will be lost.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke what is  am doing is in one page only I am showing the items in the cart and in that page only I am inserting my address and other detail.
Now when I am inserting my details and trying to delete one of the item of the cart in that case my data fill in the text box gets blank.
What I want is my data inserted in the text box does not get blank even after deleting items from cart

Comment: There is nothing in the code about a cart, or displaying its items. All you have shown is 2 forms, neither of which so anything at all except redirect. You need to show you real code so we can understand what your trying to do.

Comment: I assume at least you must have a loop to show your cart items, and you have a 'delete' button associated with each? (in which case you can make an ajax call to delete the item, and if successful, remove that item from the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added more detail on this please review

Comment: The easiest way would be to just make an ajax call to delete the item so you stay on the same page (ditto for adding the new `Request` object)

Comment: ok, I understand but is there not the way to retrive text value after the post back event?

Comment: Only if you pass it to the `Delete()` method, and from there pass it to the `ReviewRequest()` method so it can be bound to your textbox - your server is not psychic :)

Comment: can u also add the answer I had also added the code for your review

Comment: The code in your view does not relate in anyway to the image of the view you have shown so that's not really possible

Comment: "postback" is a WebForms concept. When you're using the ASP.NET MVC framework, you're dealing primarily with plain HTTP requests. There's no ViewState to provide the illusion of stateful controls, so if you want a form to display some values after a redirect, you either need to pass them in a query string or reload them from your data source when loading the page.

Comment: ok so I will store textbox value in the viewbag/tempdata and will display them in textbox on retrival